# Moodle Installation not working with local server

Tags: php

Repeatedly facing three issue while installing moodle software in local server.

1. version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.1.25
2. PHP opcode caching improves performance and lowers memory requirements, OPcache extension is recommended and fully supported.
3. It has been detected that your site is not secured using HTTPS. It is strongly recommended to migrate your site to HTTPS for increased security and improved integration with other systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question in your question, but:

1. If Moodle discovered that it's running on 5.5.5.10.1.25 PHP - then just upgrade it. If accessing the same server from network you're getting different version of PHP, then it might be that you have inconsistent packages' versions. Try removing them and adding using package manager of your choice (yum on redhat).
2. Just add opcache in yum like: `yum install php55w-opcache.x86_64`
3. It's just a message - your choice is if you use http or https.